# Xcode - File not found but build successful

Tags: xcode, hyperlink, compiler-errors, include

In my project, I've include a full "shared" folder by link (not copy) that is outside my project folder.

In the .pch file, I have `#import "MyStandardHeader.h"`

My Build settings does not have any search path to the "shared" folder.

In the "MyStandardHeader.h", I have `#import "NSMutableArrayCustom.h"` that is inside a subfolder of "shared".

I use in my code a NSMutableArrayCustom class.

I never include NSMutableArrayCustom.h

I've clean the project, quitted XCode, launched it again, build, run on both iPhone and simulator : everything works fine, but I have a red compile error: `MyStandardHeader.h - No such file or directory`

I've tried in the build settings `Always search user path`at YES and NO, it's the same.

What is the problem? Why do I have this error? How make it disappear?

Comment: I've seen this too: files that clearly exist get wonky.  Oddly, sometimes it fixes itself. It may be an Xcode bug, since the build always succeeds.  I've had success with touching the file.  sometimes a clean helps. and sometimes quitting xcode helps....  Voodoo really.

Comment: @amattn : How do you touch the file ?

Comment: just make any change, like add a space then save.

Comment: @amattn : well, that's what I did. No change. I also tried a "touch" in the console. No change. GGrrrrrr

Comment: You could try to remove the index by deleting everything in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: @amattn : I'm on XCode 4. Xcode is just an app in the Application Folder. /Devleoper/Xcode contains noting.

Comment: Sorry.  There's a tilde there.  Probably hard to see.  It means the Library folder in your home directory, not the library folder at root.

Comment: @amattn : Great, that worked ! Thank you. Could you post your comment as an answer as I can accept it ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've seen this too: files that clearly exist get wonky. Oddly, sometimes it fixes itself. It may be an Xcode bug, since the build always succeeds. I've had success with touching the file. sometimes a clean helps. and sometimes quitting xcode helps.... Voodoo really.

You could try to remove the index by deleting everything in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

That directory is a combined version of the old Build and Intermediates directories from Xcode 1,2 and 3.  Basically it's all the temporary and generated files from your project: object files, indexes, etc.

Comment: I had a similar problem, deleting DerivedData didn't help. The app would run, but I would see an error and code sense would fail to work, even though the main target worked. FIX: I found the problem was that my second target (unit test using Google Test) didn't have one of the include paths for a new library dependency that was added to the main target. Fixing the include path for the second target fixed this issue.

Answer (score 39):

I tried the steps mentioned above, but to fix the error I had to remove the file from "Copy Bundle Resources" in the project "Build Phases".

Comment: This should consider first step in the solution

Comment: This one helped me also

Comment: The answer is not totally clear. Which file? The PCH file?

Answer (score 4):

Another thing to try -- just deleting Derived Data wasn't working for me, but this did:

- Delete Derived Data using the Organizer window, Projects tab.
- In your target settings delete the value (path) set for "Prefix Header"
- Close XCode and restart.  Reload your project.  Let it re-index.
- Restore the "Prefix Header" setting.

What a major PITA.

Answer (score 1):

If deleting data and Prefix Header path doesn't work then, try to click on the File (that is not found) in the Project Navigator and uncheck the target under Target Membership in File Inspector. Then deleted the files from Project Project Navigator and add again. This is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: Unchecking the targets in `Target Membership` for the file, trying to build, letting it fail, then re-checking the boxes, and trying again -- that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Merely closing XCode (6.4) fixed my particular case of this issue.  I opened it back up, cleaned the project, and built.  Warnings were gone!  Before I closed XCode, I cleaned and built and the warnings would not leave.  So something about closing XCode did it.  Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the #import, then moved to a different line and used autocomplete to reenter the import. That error and all others like it disappeared. Strange bug.