# pbxcp issue, file not found but it's definitely there

Tags: iphone, xcode

So I've been working on different images for my app, seeing how it looks, replacing it...all has been well until earlier I replaced a file (checkmark.png) with an updated version I made, now when I build I get `pbxcp: checkmark.png: no such file or directory`. I have removed the file and re-added multiple times, I've renamed the file and replaced every instance of the file in my code with the updated name. No matter what I can't get rid of this error, all the googling I do ends up with a lot of unanswered posts, some people saying to "Clean" the project, I've tried everything I can and can't get rid of this error. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Anyone else who has this issue, I just went to Targets then Copy Bundle Resources and deleted the file in question from there. Re-added the file after that and all works fine.

Comment: you should post this as an answer. Thanks it helped me.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked..!! and yes post this as an answer..!! least people would read the comment..!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this xcode 4?  If so this might apply:

[XCode - File not found but build successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574291/xcode-file-not-found-but-build-successful/5591075#5591075)

Comment: It is xcode 4. I went to that post and tried removing everything like it said, closing and reopening, cleaning, all that stuff again...no go.

Comment: Well I fixed it, don't know why I didn't do this before. Went to Targets in the app, and looked at Copy Bundle Resources, and deleted the checkmark.png reference there. Re-added the file and now all is good to go. Thanks for your help man.

Comment: None of the fixes worked for me. Only one thing helped: I've updated my XCode from 4.2 to 4.3 :)

Comment: Issue solved. Simply click on --------.xcodeproj file where all your files are located within your opened project. Select Build Phases, Select COPY BUNDLE RESOURCES.... Then simply add your image/file. It is there I found a red label of the image that kept giving my project errors.

Answer (score 39):

Go to targets in app->built phases->copy bundle resources->remove image in red color and add one u need 
this will solve your error
thanks to DanBroChill

Comment: This is the answer. But it seems the asker himself answered his question as a comment.

Comment: It works, but it costs a lot of time. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Here is temporary solution:

**1.** Change location type from **Relative to Group** to **Absolute Path**.

**2.** Again locate file.

**3. Build** ... should be **Succeeded**.

It works in my project so I hope it helps.