# React-native looking for node_modules in ios folder

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

New to react-native. I have inherited a project and have been trying to get it up and running, with no luck. I am stuck trying to import a font. I've already added the font manually to the project via xcode, but for some reason it is looking for it in the wrong folder, and it error out. I need some help. I can show what is in my package.json or yarn.lock files if needed, but I was wondering why I get this:

```
error: /project_dir/ios/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Entypo.ttf: No such file or directory
```

it shows up in xcode as a "PBXCp Error"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've told my app where my fonts live, changed my package.json, linked the files and changed my info.plist to include them with no luck. This error still shows up

Edit: told what steps I have already taken.

Comment: In Xcode - select your top level project, then select your target (under Targets) and then select Build Phases. Take a look under Copy Bundle with Resources - do you see the missing Entypo.ttf (marked in red) in this area? Just remove it from the list. The person your inherited this project from likely moved it in here and added it to Xcode manually as well, and now Xcode is stuck looking for it here and fails when it can't find it.

Comment: For the record, my comment steals the answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642633/pbxcp-issue-file-not-found-but-its-definitely-there), so I'm going to mark this as a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be easier to follow this great tutorial https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-custom-fonts-ccc9aacf9e5e. Most likely you have not added references in your Info.plist file for iOS. Please take a look to the tutorial and let me know if it works.

Comment: I've already done this. My error happens after doing this stuff.

Comment: I see, where have you placed the `Entypo.ttf` font? and also double check your info.plist file (root/ios/projectFileName/info.plist) you should have something like this:
```<key>UIAppFonts</key>
       <array>
           <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
       </array>```